# Python tkinter: Sorting the contents of an OptionMenu widget

Tags: python, sorting, drop-down-menu, tkinter, optionmenu

Hello everyone and thanks in advance!

I've searched all around google and read almost every result i got and i still can't figure
it out, so please at least point me at some direction!
I read about pmw but i want to see if there is any way to do it with tkinter first.

I'm writing a simple enough program for DnD dice rolls and i have an OptionMenu
containing some of the dice someone needs to play. I also have an input field for entering
a die that is not included in my default options. My problem is that even though the new
option is added successfully, the options are not sorted.

I solved it at some point by destroying the OptionMenu when the new option was added,
sorting my List and then rebuilding the OptionMenu from scratch, but i was using the
place manager method at that time and i had to rewrite the program later because i had
some resolution problems. I'm using the pack manager now and destroying/rebuilding
is not an option unless i want to "re"pack all my widgets or make exclusive labels for them!

Here is a working sample of my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class DropdownExample(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill = 'both', expand = True)

        # Add Option Button
        self.addOptBtn = Button(self, text = "Add Option", command = self.add_option)

        # Option Input Field
        self.newOpt = IntVar()
        self.newOpt.set("Type a number")

        self.optIn = Entry(self)
        self.optIn['textvariable'] = self.newOpt

        # Dropdown Menu
        self.myOptions = [0, 1, 2]

        self.selOpt = IntVar()
        self.selOpt.set("Options")

        self.optMenu = OptionMenu(self, self.selOpt, *self.myOptions)

        # Positioning
        self.addOptBtn.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5)
        self.optIn.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5)
        self.optMenu.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5)


    def add_option(self):
        self.numToAdd = ""
        self.counter = 0

        try:
            self.numToAdd = int(self.optIn.get())                                           # Integer validation

            while self.counter < len(self.myOptions):                                       # Comparison loop & error handling
                if self.numToAdd == self.myOptions[self.counter]:
                    print("Already exists!")                    
                    break;

                elif self.numToAdd < 0:
                    print("No less than 0!")
                    break;

                elif self.counter < len(self.myOptions)-1:
                    self.counter += 1

                else:                                                                       # Dropdown menu option addition
                    self.myOptions.append(self.numToAdd)
                    self.myOptions.sort()

                    self.optMenu['menu'].add_command(label = self.numToAdd)

                    self.selOpt.set(self.numToAdd)

                    print("Added succesfully!")

                    self.counter += 2

        except ValueError:
            print("Type ONLY numbers!")


def runme():
    app = DropdownExample()
    app.master.title("Dropdown Menu Example")
    app.master.resizable(0, 0)
    app.mainloop()

runme()
```

I am using Python 3.3 on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a set of [`insert_something()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.insert-method)  methods in `Menu`. You must keep your list sorted with each insert ([bisect](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/bisect.html) module).

```
from tkinter import *
import bisect

...
                else:                                                                       # Dropdown menu option addition
                    index = bisect.bisect(self.myOptions, self.numToAdd)
                    self.myOptions.insert(index, self.numToAdd)
                    self.optMenu['menu'].insert_command(index, label=self.numToAdd)
                    self.selOpt.set(self.numToAdd)
                    print("Added succesfully!", self.myOptions)
                    self.counter += 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great and does exactly what i need. I didn't know about the _bisect_ module. I read somewhere about inserting index specific items into my menu, but i had trouble getting the index i needed. It all makes sense now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:

```
self.optMenu['menu'].add_command(label = self.numToAdd)
```

with:

```
for dit in self.myOptions:
    self.optMenu['menu'].delete(0)
for dat in self.myOptions:
    self.optMenu['menu'].add_command(label = dat)
```

The gotcha is that "add_command" takes the item to add to the menu, while "delete" takes the index of the item.

Comment: That way also works but there is another problem. Once i add an option to the menu, i can't chose any other. I have almost the same problem with @kalgasnik 's answer, i can enter a new number, sort the menu but i can ONLY choose one of the default options. All the other just appear. The myOptions list is updated, the menu list is updated so my guess is that it has something to do with updating the optMenu['menu']. (I might be completely wrong about that ^^ ). I will look into it a bit further and post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that whatever way i choose to follow on this one, it all comes down to updating
the widget.
Updating a frame usually redraws a portion or the whole frame if needed.
So i went back to square one. I destroyed the widget, updated the list and then created it again.
As for the position, i used a label as a background only for the OptionMenu.
That way i can delete/replace my OptionMenu as i please, without moving any widgets around, as long as it stays inside it's label and it's the only one in there and of course as long as i don't move any labels.

This probably is a workaround, not a solution, but it get's the job done and with a bit
of optimization it can be used for any other widget having the same problem.

```
from tkinter import *

class DropdownExample(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill = 'both', expand = True)

        # Add Option Button
        self.addOptBtn = Button(self, text = "Add Option", command = self.add_option)

        # Option Input Field
        self.newOpt = IntVar()
        self.newOpt.set("Type a number")

        self.optIn = Entry(self)
        self.optIn['textvariable'] = self.newOpt

        # Dropdown Menu
        # menu's label
        self.optMenuLabel = Label(self)

        # option menu
        self.myOptions = [0, 1, 2]

        self.selOpt = IntVar()
        self.selOpt.set("Options")

        self.optMenu = OptionMenu(self.optMenuLabel, self.selOpt, *self.myOptions)

        # Positioning
        self.addOptBtn.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5)
        self.optIn.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5)
        self.optMenuLabel.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5)
        self.optMenu.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5)


    def add_option(self):
        self.numToAdd = ""
        self.counter = 0

        try:
            self.numToAdd = int(self.optIn.get())                                           # Integer validation

            while self.counter < len(self.myOptions):                                       # Comparison loop & error handling
                if self.numToAdd == self.myOptions[self.counter]:
                    print("Already exists!")                    
                    break;

                elif self.numToAdd < 0:
                    print("No less than 0!")
                    break;

                elif self.counter < len(self.myOptions)-1:
                    self.counter += 1

                else:                                                                       # Dropdown menu option addition
                    self.myOptions.append(self.numToAdd)
                    self.myOptions.sort()

                    self.selOpt.set(self.numToAdd)

                    self.optMenu.destroy()
                    self.optMenu = OptionMenu(self.optMenuLabel, self.selOpt, *self.myOptions)
                    self.optMenu.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5)

                    print("Added succesfully!", self.myOptions)
                    break;

        except ValueError:
            print("Type ONLY numbers!")


def runme():
    app = DropdownExample()
    app.master.title("Dropdown Menu Example")
    app.master.resizable(0, 0)
    app.mainloop()

runme()
```